# php array inserting line break when writing to text file

Tags: php

When parsing a text file full of variables (one on each line, no whitespace after), after processing, it's being written to a $myfile with an additional line after.

Please checkout my code:

```
$txt_file    = file_get_contents('spins/' . $skustart . '/' . $skustart . '.txt');
$rows        = explode("\n", $txt_file);
array_shift($rows);
$row_data = $data;
foreach($rows as $row => $data)
{
    //parent

    $txt = $skustart. "-" . $a.$skip1.$slogan . " " . $data . $sloganb . ' Tee Shirt, Men\'s ' . $skip3 . $brand . $desc . $value . $tee .  $item_type . $skip20 . $skip9 .  $bullet_point1 . $bullet_point2 . $value . $bullet_point212 . $bullet_point3 . $bullet_point4 . $bullet_point5 . $value  . $gen_k1 . $value  . $gen_k2 .  $value  . $gen_k3 .  $value  . $gen_k4 .  $value  . $gen_k5 . $main_image_url1 . $img_folder_name . "/" . $skustart. "-" . $a . '-black' . $main_image_url1_format . $other_image_url1 . $skip10 . $parent . " ; ;" . $variation_theme . $skip18 .  $department_name .  " ; ;" . $skip2 .$skip2 .  $skip18 . "\n"; //this is the parent
    fwrite($myfile, $txt);


    //end parent
```

Here is what is spit out:

***Note: 10K Run is the variable in question ($data)***

```
xxx-110K Run
blk-Sm;XXXXXXXBlack;black;; ;mens;; ;; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ;Small;Small;
```

Where it should be:

```
xxx-110K Run blk-Sm;XXXXXXXBlack;black;; ;mens;; ;; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ;Small;Small;
```

I'm not sure what is causing this, the code seems to work fine until I implement it into this generator.

Please advise or provide any suggestions, thank you very much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved.

Changed

```
$rows        = explode("\n", $txt_file);
```

To

```
$rows        = explode("\r\n", $txt_file);
```

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1):

Example code is pretty unfinished, so I will make suggestions about your main problem only - why there are 2 strings.

That is probably because you have such string in the input:
xxx-110K Run **\n**blk-Sm;XXXXXXXBlack;black;; ;mens;;...
But your text editor don't show this as separate strings. This happens with different combiantions of \n\r  or   \r\n   or  \n

You can delete all "\r" in first, to check if it is a case.

Trim all values in $rows also can help sometimes.

Comment: Actually added \r and it worked. Didn't think about trying it until you mentioned it. Thanks!

Comment: Answer isn't necessarily correct. Comment said to delete all "\r" when in fact, the solution was to add "\r".

I gave credit as correct answer because A. Denis made me think of it. I actually showed the correct answer in my post below.